# Event when YouTube video finished

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, dom-events

I have simple html code that plays YouTube video after click on the image:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div id="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
<object width="1280" height="745">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/kCfP003Btjw?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/kCfP003Btjw?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="1280" height="745"></embed>
</object>

</div>


<img src="https://i.qmyimage.com/mgen/global/zGetImageNew.ms?args=%22shpimg4198.jpg%22,425,96,1" id="imageID" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#imageID').click(function() {
$('#ytapiplayer2').show();
$('#imageID').hide();
});
</script>
</body>
```

I need hide the video and show image back, after video finished play. How is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Youtube has a JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

What you need is the [onStateChange](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) event, which will give you 0 when ended.

```
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
    if(state === 0){
        // the video is end, do something here.
    }
});
```

Comment: hm, I added to my code, player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state) {
    if (state === 0) {
        alert('end');
    }
}); 
 but event doesn't occur!

Comment: perhaps you have to change the way you embed the video, see examples here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Examples and remember to load the api script

Comment: state is an object. You have to check for state.data === 0 (I used &enablejsapi=1&version=3 in the iframe url)

Comment: Note that the JavaScript API is now deprecated; it is recommended that you use the IFrame API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference which has similar methods for state change.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible on a live stream aswell?

Comment: @VictorÖhrström did you know how to get end livestream event of youtube.

Comment: @ManojPatidar No when i was in need of this youtube didn't have any support for this, i don't know if they have added it later.