# how to implement JS to two pieces of HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

For example: i have two different pieces of HTML codes, one is an embedded YouTube video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kZlXWp6vFdE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and this is a question about the video:

```
<form>
    <h3> How was the video? </h3>
    <input type="button"name="option1" /> Good!
    <br/>
    <input type="button"name="option2" /> Bad!
</form>
```

What i wanna do now, is when a user navigates to this page, he is gonna see the video first, and then after watching the video he will click on next and the question will appear.

I don't want the next button to link to a different page where the question is, the question has to load on the same page.

The simplest form i can put this in that,

- a user navigates to the page.
- watches video and clicks next.
- the video disappears and the question appears.

Comment: You shouldn't use iframe then

Comment: You could use youtube API to get videos from there and then you can do anything because this is your domain. https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

Comment: Do you need to check if the video has been played entirely ? Or can the next button be clicked at any time ?

Comment: the youtube video and the question form was just an example. the main thing is that, is there a way to show an html code and then click next, and hide that html code and show the next one, and click next hide the html and show next, blablabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kZlXWp6vFdE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<form id="form" style="display:none;">
    <h3> How was the video? </h3>
    <input type="button"name="option1" /> Good!
    <br/>
    <input type="button"name="option2" /> Bad!
</form>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

And the js:

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs73d/2/

Comment: nice! exactly what i needed, now what about previous. What if i wanna go back and watch the video.

Comment: thanks, is there a way that i can easily add more content to the html and when someone presses next again, another video would appear, then the question, then the video. Is there a way to add content and dont make any changes to the JS when i add new content?

Comment: I don't think so, you'll need to write some javascript. Take a look at jquery, it could make it easier

Comment: do you have any experience in jQuery? can you show me how its done?

Comment: You should open a new question for that, explaining more precisely what you want

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of doing this, would be to use the Chromeless Youtube Player API. This would allow you to add an event handler through JS to check for when the video has finished playing. You could then proceed to show the form.

[This similar question may be of help to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished)

Comment: the youtube video and the question form was just an example. the main thing is that, is there a way to show an html code and then click next, and hide that html code and show the next one, and click next hide the html and show next, blablabla

Comment: @Antoine's answer (above) will suit your needs perfectly then :) Have you looked into the jQuery library btw? Doing things like this with jQuery is as simple as $("#video").hide(); $("#questionForm").show();

Comment: can you show edit your post above and show me how to do it with jQuery, Thanks, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add a button quickly, probably below the iframe:

```
<input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext"/>
```

Make sure that your form is hidden when the page loads, you can do this a number of ways, I'll just add some inline CSS for times sake:

```
<form style="display: none;">
```

I'm adding an ID to your iFrame, this will make it easier to target:

```
<iframe id="iYoutubeVid" ../>
```

Now for the JS:

```
document.getElementById("btnNext").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("iYoutubeVid").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btnNext").style.display = "";
}
```

The "Next" button will always be available to click with this example. I'd suggest the Youtube API if you're looking for something more complex.