# Javascript event to catch when a Youtube video ends

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube-api, dom-events

I've some videos integrated through WordPress as iframe.

What I'm looking for is to redirect users to the homepage as soon as the video finishes playing.

Is there any event in Javascript to catch when existing Youtube video stops?

Comment: Check this post for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've checked that already. But I thought the post is from 2012 and It's Mid of 2014. 2 of these years nothing have been changed? However thanks a lot. Do you think it'll work on existing iframes? not youtube api generated iframes.

Comment: Also if you could help me little bit on this. Where the "player" object comes from? How to define the player object?

Comment: how many iframe videos do you have in the page?

Comment: I have one video in each page. Total 10-12 videos on individual pages. Will be adding more.

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html

Comment: Seen that as well. :) Couldn't make this working yet. :(

Comment: did you try the below code?

Comment: Yes. I already did. It didn't work. However I'm giving it another and try and letting you know if it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your code that you are trying here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    // first video
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
            'onReady': function(){ alert("Ready!"); },
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        console.log('player stopped');
    }
}
```

Above code will work if your iframe looks as below

```
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZdP0KM49IVk?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />
```

with `id=player` and `?enablejsapi=1`

Comment: Thanks a lot sathishn. You made my day. It's working now. :) I made a silly mistake that time. I didn't remove the oembed from the url generated by WordPress. Take Care

Comment: enablejsapi=1 saved me. Thanks