# Callback function is not working for HTML5 Video player

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, html5-video

I am creating HTML Video Player. so that i have used "http://www.videojs.com/" plugin. 
In the below code the player is created is succesfully.

```
 <video id="example_video_1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ" }'>
 </video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example_video_1").bind("ended", function() {
        alert("I'm done! Here is the Callback");
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that how would i know that video is finished ?
for that i have wrote the code but it is not working . Can you help me ?

Thankx in advance

Comment: in the documentation of videojs I've found this: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#ended-event Perhaps that's what you're looking for? Not sure if that's the most responsive solution, but you may add a callback on that function. Also, where is your videojs object?

Comment: Hey, Id for your video tag is "vid1" while in the javascript you are using $("#example_video_1"). That could be your problem.

Comment: hii Vira . No its not becouse of that . I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video.js, will replace your `<video>` element if you use a "tech" other than "html5". A "tech" can be Flash or some plugin, as in your case, which is YouTube. So what's happening here is that you're attaching your callback to the video element and then, when Video.js replaces that element, it has no way to know that you've attached the callback, so your callback gets lost.

Instead, you need to attach the callback to the Video.js object. But you need to be careful because that object doesn't exist until after Video.js gets a chance to scan for your video element, which hasn't happened yet when your script executes. So there are a couple options.

1) Create the Video.js object directly in Javascript, as in [the example](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/blob/master/examples/javascript.html).

2) Wait for a while. Like this:

```
$(function () {
    videojs('example_video_1').on('ended', function () {
        //todo: that voodoo that you do so well
    });
});
```

That second example may depend on exactly how/where you've got the video.js scripts loading. So if that doesn't work, try option 1.

Answer (score 0):

The "bind" function in jQuery is deprecated. Use the [.on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example_video_1").on("ended", function() {
        alert("I'm done! Here is the Callback");
    });
</script>
```

---

The above solution should work for all videos which are locally embedded. Since the asker mentioned in the comments below he's using a youtube embed, I'll post a solution for an embedded video.

Youtube provides a [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) for its videos.

The [onStateChange](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) method provides the functionality you're looking for:

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementById('example_video_1');
    video.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
        if(state === 0){
            alert("I'm done here!");
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished) question.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? This code works fine for me.

Comment: hi madhippie it is not working for me . Actually i have intigreted youtube videos instead of other one .

Comment: I added a solution for the youtube API.