# YTPlayerView video did Ended iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am using `YTPlayerView` to play a youtube video . And I need to do some actions when the video reached its end and finished playing. 
Is there any way to catch the event when the video finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this class delegate `YTPlayerViewDelegate`.
The specific method you need is:

```
- (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state {
    switch (state) {
       case kYTPlayerStateEnded:
       NSLog(@"Ended");
       break;
    case kYTPlayerStatePaused:
       NSLog(@"Paused");
       break;
    default:
       break;
   }
}
```

You can also check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

Comment: This does not fully work for me. I get a `kYTPlayerStatePaused` state when the users pauzes the video but also when the video is dismissed with the 'done' button..