# Embedded Youtube Video Autoplay - In the middle of an image sildeshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, slideshow

Looking for some help to get a video embedded from youtube working as item number 4 in a slideshow of images. The end result should be that the first 3 images are played and once it reaches the the 4th item being the video it should autoplay it, once the video finishes it should move on top the next image in the slideshow.

My website is www.serenitygardenrooms.com

My code snippet that isnt working is:

```
<section id="home-slider" class="flexslider fullbg"
 style="background-image:url(img/slide/home/1_1_.jpg); height:600px; padding:0px;">
```

Scape. Scope. Style. Context.

```
        <p class="home-slide-content bounceIn animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="10s">
            We <span class="highlight">build</span> it
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="home-slide">
    <div class="flex-caption transparent light-font center flexslider fullbg" style="background-image:url(img/slide/home/2.jpg); height:600px; width:100%; padding:0px; margin-top:0px;">
        <p class="home-slide-content bounceInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="10s" style="margin-top:150px;">
            Scape. <span class="highlight">Scope.</span> Style.<span class="highlight"> Context.</span>
        </p>

        <p class="home-slide-content bounceIn animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="10s">
            We <span class="highlight">build</span> it
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="home-slide">
    <div class="flex-caption transparent light-font center flexslider fullbg" style="background-image:url(img/slide/home/3.jpg); height:600px; width:100%; padding:0px; margin-top:0px;">
        <p class="home-slide-content bounceInLeft animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="10s" style="margin-top:150px;">
            Scape. <span class="highlight">Scope.</span> Style.<span class="highlight"> Context.</span>
        </p>

        <p class="home-slide-content bounceIn animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s" data-wow-duration="10s">
            We <span class="highlight">build</span> it
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="home-slide">
    <div class="flex-caption transparent light-font center flexslider fullbg" style="background-image:url(img/slide/home/4.jpg); height:600px; width:100%; padding:0px; margin-top:0px;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyjK8mjhjb4?autoplay=1" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an event to catch ended event like in HTML5 video's.
There is a similar question:

[Event when youtube video finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished)