# How to trigger an event when video ends inside an iframe using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am looking to trigger an event when video finishes playing, here is the following iframe I am using:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="home-content-slider">
        <div class="home-content-inner">
            <iframe id="vid1" src="<%= post %>" width="" height="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to contact their development team?

Comment: You should check video service provider for callbacks.

Comment: Rather than editing a question into an entirely new question, it is better just to ask a new question. Only the above comments have been invalidated by this edit, so I will leave it be - if answers had been invalidated I would be rolling back the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2aho8vo/), demonstrating Vimeo video embedding example with alert on video play and completed

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/66966424" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>

    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', function() {
        alert('You have played the video')
    });
        player.on('ended', function(){
        alert('Video play completed');
    });

    player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('title:', title);
    });
</script>
```

[Vimeo API Reference](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js)

Comment: i don't know why people had down voted this, if you think this question useful then please upvote and thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Insomania I think your question might've been downvoted because it lacks information. The fact that it's a Vimeo video for instance is an important piece of information that should've been included in the question. PS: I gave you the same answer as the one that you accepted an hour earlier ;)

Comment: Agree with @vi5ion on down vote. You should ask question in proper way with details.

Answer (score 2):

In case you really need to use *iframe*:

Create a seprate page say **video.html**, accept required video playing parameters using **URL** query string parameters and finally draw playing using video service API. [Example of using YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished)

Now use iframe to open **video.html** as source and pass required parameters to show video player.

Comment: in my case, video is not Youtube video, it's vimeo

Answer (score 1):

I read in your comment to another answer that the included video is from Vimeo. In that case you can use the Vimeo JavaScript API: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js

Then you can do something like:

```
var player = new Vimeo.Player('vid1');

player.getEnded().then(function(ended) {
  // ended = whether or not the video has ended
}).catch(function(error) {
  // an error occurred
});
```

Comment: thanks to you too @vi5ion, i really appreciate your efforts and for sharing this useful info :)