# Play youtube video without controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

I need to play a youtube video inside WPF as a ScreenSaver. That is why I have to disable all controls and auto-play it.

additionally need an information when the video have ended.

Any help ? :)

Comment: It is incredibly unclear what you are asking here. Is there something you tried/some research you made already? What do you mean with _disable all controls_?

Comment: Did a research. Found loads of youtube video inside a web-view. But then you are not able to get end of video information. (need that to change screen saver - my screen savers currently have images / videos). Found one solution that had everything I needed but It needed creation of html page that play a youtube video that have a script which is getting information of video callback. Asked for advice - meaby shorter way.
By disabling controls I ment that controlls are not avaible - i.e you dont see lower bar, at the end of video you dont see repeat/ next video propositions etc.

Comment: this is page I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773322/event-when-youtube-video-finished

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code and follow the tutorial at [this](http://www.hikmetokumus.com/makale/92/csharp-ile-youtube-video-oynatma%22) link. (Sadly not in english, you can use a translator.)

```
private void YouTube_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "http://www.youtube.com/v/xYRSt-bJggc";  
}
```